# How to add architectural plan to arcgis javascript 2D map

Tags: arcmap, javascript, 2d

I would like to know if there is a way to add an architectural plan to my 2D map with a fixed position.

Somewhat similar to BuildingSceneLayer , but for a 2d map.

Note that I am working on an Angular 11 project having ArcGIS javascript version 4.17

Comment: Could you help me with " Fixed Position" what do you exactly mean by that?

Comment: @YogeshChavan i mean i want to show it in a specific location & site & direction on the map.